# How do I exit a do loop when I press the cancel button

Tags: excel, vba, macos, inputbox, do-loops

```
Sub msgbox_icons()
    Dim t As String, arg As Integer
    t = "Message Box Icons Demo"
    Do
        arg = InputBox(prompt:="Enter below one of the integers: (16, 32, 48 or 64):", Title:=t)
        If arg = 16 Then
            MsgBox arg & "<=> Critical Message Icon", vbCritical + vbOK, t
        ElseIf arg = 32 Then
            MsgBox arg & "<=> Warning Query Icon", vbQuestion + vbOK, t
        ElseIf arg = 48 Then
            MsgBox arg & "<=> Warning Message Icon", vbExclamation + vbOK, t
        ElseIf arg = 64 Then
            MsgBox arg & "<=> Information Message Icon", vbInformation + vbOK, t
        Else
            MsgBox arg & "<=> non-existent icon type", vbOKCancel, t
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

When I press the cancel button, it tells me I have a type 13 error. I was wondering how to fix it. Also how would I end the macro if I press the cancel button for both the input box and message box. Thanks.

Comment: Which line does the error occur on?

Answer (score 4):

since the return value of the cancel button is an empty string the arg varible must be a string, then asking if it is numeric you can tell if the pressed the cancel button, use the "Exit Do" to exit the loop, your code could be like this:

```
Sub msgbox_icons()
    Dim arg, t As String

    t = "Message Box Icons Demo"
    Do
        arg = InputBox(Prompt:="Enter below one of the integers: (16, 32, 48 or 64):", Title:=t)
        If Not IsNumeric(arg) Then
            Exit Do
        ElseIf arg = 16 Then
            MsgBox(arg & "<=> Critical Message Icon", vbCritical + vbOK, t)
        ElseIf arg = 32 Then
            MsgBox(arg & "<=> Warning Query Icon", vbQuestion + vbOK, t)
        ElseIf arg = 48 Then
            MsgBox(arg & "<=> Warning Message Icon", vbExclamation + vbOK, t)
        ElseIf arg = 64 Then
            MsgBox(arg & "<=> Information Message Icon", vbInformation + vbOK, t)
        Else
            MsgBox(arg & "<=> non-existent icon type", vbOKCancel, t)
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Note: currently `arg` is a variant. VBA defaults variables to variant unless **each** variable is **explicitly** assigned a particular type.

Comment: @mistella in this answer that would be deliberate and necessary to avoid the error when Esc is pressed

Comment: @misael you need to remove the `()` around the MsgBox arguments

Comment: @chrisneilsen I just wanted to explicitly state/clarify that, because I have seen multiple instances where people use this format expecting `arg` to be defined as a String, or use something like `Dim t, c as Integer` and expect `t` to be an Integer as a result. (Also, from how @Misael says that `the arg variable must be a string` it implies the (mis)understanding that that is how `arg` is being defined in the code)

Comment: @mistella rereading the post I agree, the OP probably intended `arg` to be a String.